# How to impose contract to subclass from parent class implementation

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

If I have an interface and I want the functions in my interface to be implemented in my sub class but the parent class must implement the interface. And Sub class extends Parent Class.

Here is what I want.

```
interface MyInterface {
   public function find();
}


class B implements MyInterface {
}

class A extends B {
}
```

But an error is thrown saying find() function must be added in class B.

Anyone who could enlighten me on what am I doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Dear down voters, please comment or explain why you down vote so that you can help me grow more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Interface** is a structure, which contains a set of fields and methods that have to be implemented in every class that implements this interface. If your `B` class `implements MyInterface` it means it has to implement all of its methods/fields.

```
interface MyInterface
{
     public function find();
}

class B implements MyInterface {
    public function find()
    {
       echo "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Does `A` class have to implement this method too? I'll leave it as your homework.

Comment: interface is NOT an abstract class

Comment: @tereško, woah, ye, you're right, why did I... Fixed, thanks.